How to search a mathematical symbol in Overleaf?
This may not be a tex-related question. Sorry if it does not fit in this community.
I am writing a paper with other researchers on Overleaf. I would like to search a symbol within the whole paper. It is a mathematical symbol so searching it within the generated pdf file does not work. On the other hand, each section is a stand-along tex file and \input{section name} is used in the main file. So searching in the main file does not work. Is there a way other than searching in the tex files for sections one by one?

This sounds very much like an Overleaf-specific question. Please contact the Overleaf helpdesk directly for Overleaf-specific questions.

You can download the project and search locally. Though Linux provides better tools, even for Windows you can specify a path and content to search. Some even provide regular expressions, if you need it.

most pdf viewers will allow you to search for unicode math symbols, and most editors will allow you to search across multiple files not having to search "one by one" so it is not really clear what your specific problem is,
